# Angular2 components or module npm package

Tags: angular, npm

I want to build a npm package with my Angular2 components.

Do I need to create an angular module and export it or could I just export my components?

What are the benefits of each approach?

Examples would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you export only components you have to import and resolve all the dependencies that the components need.

If you export module that already has provided all the dependencies then you have to only add the module to the imports.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#angular-modularity

Comment: How do I provide all the dependencies in the module I export?

Comment: Meaning that you have to add the components you use to the `declarations` array example